# Cannot import ttk in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, spyder, ttk

I am trying to import ttk from tkinter. I am following instructions from this [website](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html):

I am using Spyder on mac with OS Mojave, on Spyder, python version is 3.8.6 (according to sys.version)

My code is:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
runfile('/Users/Tom/untitled0.py', wdir='/Users/Tom')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/Tom/untitled0.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tkinter import ttk

ImportError: cannot import name 'ttk' from 'tkinter' (/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python38.zip/tkinter/__init__.pyc)
```

Comment: What is your environment? Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: When I ran your code I didn't seem to be getting any errors. Make sure you have installed python correctly and have added it to PATH

Comment: Hi Pouya Esmaeili, I have python version 3.8.6.

Comment: Omid Ki, what do you mean add to PATH?

Comment: do you have a file named "tkinter.py"? What happens if you do `print(tk.__file__)` immediately after importing tkinter?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please open an issue about this in our [issue tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues). I don't know why `ttk` is missing from our Mac app, but we can try to fix it for our next release.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The problem happened because `Tk` was not included in our Mac application. However, that's fixed now in our 4.2.5 or any 5 versions.